# Adding another print queue to same printer "Win 2003 server"

Tags: printer, windows-server-2003

So as topic mentions, I have a print server on a Windows 2003 Server
Installed on that that I have a Xerox Workstation 7345.

I wish to create another print queue on that Xerox Workstation.. so I thought I would just do
'add Printer'.. these are the steps I take, and what happens.

Add Printer -> network Printer -> Find printer "I search for the name and It finds it, with full name" -> do you wish to add this printer? -> Finished.

but I still only have that 1 printer added.. its like it just confirms the one I already have..
I figured it might be because it has the exact same name as the printer already added, but I don't get any option of changing that name..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can trick it - try adding a new instance with the incorrect print driver and a different printer name, and then after it is installed change the driver to the appropriate one.

Comment: Hey I'm not sure how, It won't allow me to add a printer unless I pick one from the list.. and the ones on the list I pick from are the ones already installed... so evil circle on that one.

Comment: When you install it, are you not prompted for a driver location? If so, choose manually and choose Generic

Comment: no I'm not.. 
I select After I pick 'network printer.. I get the following choices
"Find printer" <- The one I use
"Connect to a printer, Name"
"Connect to a printer, URL" 

when I pick 'find printer'.. it lists the one I have already installed, and when I select one of those it just tells me it has been added with that name.. 

I took some screenshots : http://i45.tinypic.com/2j4of88.jpg

Comment: I'm on XP here at work - I will try when I get home to my W7 box (in about 8 hours). I expect you'll have an answer before hand, but if not I will see what I can do.

Comment: well I suspect I wont get an answer untill you are back :) .. and btw. don't know if you saw it, but its win 2003 server..

Comment: OK. You can also try to add the printer as a local printer, then create a new port - this may let you get round the issue

Comment: alright so it worked by adding a local printer on TCP IP.. even though it wasn't local.. and then adding afterwards changing port.

Comment: Glad it's worked for you